# Remove element from jQuery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have some sibling DOM elements that exist only within a jQuery selection:

```
var $container = $('<div></div><span></span>');
```

I want $div to only contain `<div></div>`, so I try to remove the `<span>`:

```
$container.find('span').remove();
// Note that span still exists:
console.log($div.length === 2);
```

What's the right way to solve this?

Comment: since you changed the html in an edit... use `$container.filter('span').remove()` since span is at root of the object now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't modify the current selection so this isn't ideal, but I ended up finding a solution using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$div = $div.not('span')
```

Answer (score 4):

Your current selection is your `<div>` element. You need to find your span within there and call [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) on that.

The parameter passed to `.remove()` does not find elements within the current collection, it filters it.

```
var $div = $('<div><span></span></div>');
$div.find('span').remove();
```

Comment: Shoot, thanks for catching my typo. Now that that's working, the example I gave doesn't actually seem to capture the problem I'm having. I'll see if I can update my question to reflect the issue I'm having - if not, I'll just go ahead and accept this.

Comment: Ok, the issue is actually when the elements are siblings. Updated my question.